# Looking for a Book Which Discusses the Standards of Rigor in Newton's Principia

Tags: classical-mechanics

About an year ago, I had seen an article somewhere on the internet which discussed Newton's Principia Mathematica and the rigor (or lack thereof) of the arguments presented.

I have forgotten who the author was and am unable to find the article back.

> Is there a published book in which similar work has been done?

I am trying to write a term paper in my History of Math course for which I think this could be a suitable topic.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that I had inadvertently triggered a downvote while scrolling through pages earlier today.