# Looking for a Book Which Discusses the Rigor in Newton's Principia Mathematica

Tags: physics, reference-request, classical-mechanics

About an year ago, I had seen an article somewhere on the internet which discussed Newton's Principia Mathematica and the rigor (or lack thereof) of the arguments presented.

I have forgotten who the author was and am unable to find the article back.

> Is there a published book in which similar work has been done?

I am trying to write a term paper in my History of Math course for which I think this could be a suitable topic.

I accidently created the [same post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2637/looking-for-a-book-which-discusses-the-standards-of-rigor-in-newtons-principia?rq=1) with a different account and was unable to delete it.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of the previous question.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Yes. That's what I said in the last line.

Comment: Reading Principia mathematica itself is much more interesting and useful than a book discussing its rigor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might be of interest to you:
https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/isaac-newton-mathematical-certainty-and-method

Comment: mdh, although the OP apparently found this answer useful, we have to keep in mind that this website should cater to anyone who happens to be interested in the answer, not just the OP. Therefore, I would like you to expand your answer a bit and perhaps say something about the book, giving general information or even tell something about your experiences, if any, with it.